# How to use .so files in an AAR fo a JNI andriod project?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, build.gradle, aar

I am working on creating an AAR which is downloaded by the build server at compile time, it will contain a C++ pre compiled library, which will have the .so files within it. I have already got the c++ and the AAR with the respective files completed. I am not however able to consume it by my simple test application made for testing the library.

Clearly the issue is I have not told the project how to link the contents of the AAR in a way the JNI can load it. I just cant seem to find out how one is to use these AAR files for .so resources, which is a hard requirement. It is as if after it compiles with the `implementation project` that it is missing the /jni folder (which is clearly in its compressed contents)

I confirmed I have the .so files in the AAR with a plugin. It shows

```
-jni
   -x86
      libmyproject.so
   -armeabi-v7a
      libmyproject.so
```

in addition the other lib/res/assets etc that I do not care about.

Running my project I see the expected files in build/aar with myproject-Android-release and build/aar-debug with myproject-Android-debug.aar. Which is where I want them.

In my settings.gradle I have

```
include ':myproject-Android-debug',':myproject-Android-release'
```

In my build.gradle I have

```
import xxx

buildscript {
    apply plugin: 'xxxx'
    dependencies {
        classpath brazil.tool('AndroidGradle', 'AndroidSDK', 'KotlinGradlePlugin', 'xxxx')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'xxx'
apply plugin: 'xxx-android-sdk'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'xxx-android'


configurations {
    ktlint
}

dependencies {
    implementation brazil.build()
    testImplementation xxx.testbuild()
    ktlint brazil.tool('Ktlint')
    implementation project(":myproject-Android-debug")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion SDK.platformVersion.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion SDK.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
            //possibly here?
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "/META-INF/proguard/**"
    }
}

task ktlint(type: JavaExec) {
    inputs.files(project.fileTree(dir: "src", include: "**/*.kt"))
    outputs.dir("${buildDir}/reports/ktlint/")
    group = 'verification'
    main = "com.github.xxxx"
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    args = [
            "--reporter=plain",
            "--reporter=checkstyle,output=${buildDir}/reports/ktlint/ktlint-report.xml",
            "src/**/*.kt"
    ]
}
check.dependsOn ktlint

task ktlintFormat(type: JavaExec) {
    group = 'verification'
    main = "xxx"
    classpath = xxx
}
```

Crash output

```
2020-04-24 01:20:57.150 10387-10387/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.testapp, PID: 10387
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.testapp-4-XMV-9aZlJXyboIRl92bA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmyproject.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
at com.company.project.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.kt:33)
```

Comment: The crash output says it is looking under `<APK>/lib/x86` while your post says you have a `jni/x86_64/libmyproject.so`. Also, what is inside the final APK in terms of native libraries?

Comment: Why are you setting your `abiFilters` to `"armeabi-v7a", "x86"` when the native libraries you have are for arm64-v8a and x86_64?

Comment: I switched out the abi packages, didn't realize that was in the stacktrace. Those are correct. Updated the question

Comment: if you analyze the apk, is the .so file included? i'm running into a similar, but not quite the same, issue...my .so is included the first time i download the .aar from maven repo, but subsequent builds that get a new version of .aar, the .apk that is built, the .so is not included...havent found an answer yet, but maybe you have the same problem that the .so is not in the .apk?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Deuschami after 1.5 years I don't recall. I think I ended up with a different solution. If I had come up with an answer I would have provided it at the time. That said these kinds of comments really don't add to the question. If you find an answer please link it here.

Comment: @Deuschami How did you solve this issue? Could you share the different solution here which could help.